# How to stop Safari showing 'Log in' popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field where the user can enter some text, and a button. For some reason though, Safari shows up their new saved username feature as soon as the page loads, even though it's not a log in form. Is there any way to disable this?

```html
<input id="textfield" placeholder="Enter Here"></input>
<button id="submit" onclick="runsearch()">Submit</button>
```

Safari Message

[image: Safari Message]

Thanks

Comment: try this `<input id="textfield" placeholder="Enter Here" autocomplete="off"></input>`

Comment: Most likely not related to your problem, but there is no close input tag: `</input>`

Comment: Could you provide a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Tuning autocomplete didn't help.